# You left off on page 50

Tags: word-usage

I am a teacher and I am having a class right now. I have just forgotten what I taught in the last class . So I ask the kids:

Where did I leave off in the last class?

One of them said?

***You left off on page 50 (of the book I'm teaching).***

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

I would be glad if you answered my question. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["This is Figure 7 on page 777" or "This is Figure 7 on the page 777"? Why not "the"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152948/this-is-figure-7-on-page-777-or-this-is-figure-7-on-the-page-777-why-not-t)

Comment: You can be proud of your pupil. His answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, the sequence of *off* and then *on* is perfectly normal and correct.

Comment: I'm puzzled as to what caused you to doubt that it was grammatical.

Comment: I am a follower of Rene Descartes. He said : Doubt paves the way for reaching certainty. For this reason, I asked this question. Moreover, I'm not a native speaker and I should consult the members of this great site before saying a sentence. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Although you used the verb 'leave off' first it sounds as though perhaps you are unsure of how it works ...

Comment: @ColinFine presumably its the *left off on* where we see too words with potentially opposite meanings.

Comment: @Araucaria: that is evidently your presumption, as shown by your earlier comment, and you may well be right. I had no idea what keramus found problematic in the sentence.

Comment: I wondered whether using leave off in this context is correct or not. Dear members did me a favor and answered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You left off on page 50 (of the book I'm teaching).*

**This sentence is grammatically correct in every way.**

1. To *leave off* is a phrasal verb meaning "come to an end, stop or cease" ([Princeton WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=leave%20off))
2. The correct preposition "on" is used:

> ON (meaning #4): used to say where something is written or shown:
>
> *There’s a diagram on page 25.*

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/on_1))

3. There's no definite article before *page* as it should be omitted in this case:

> **There is no article before a noun followed by a categorizing letter or
> number**:
>
> *The students have just read section C.*
>
> *The Chicago train is about to depart from track 5.*
>
> *Her flight leaves from gate 32.*
>
> *He fell asleep on page 816 of "War and Peace".*
>
> *She is staying in room 689.*

(http://www.davidappleyard.com/english/articles.htm)